# input hidden or div with display: none in css?

Tags: html, css

In our project we both use `input` `type=hidden` elements and `divs` with `display:none` css for storing some data on html page without showing it to user.

So i wonder which way is more suitable in both performance and code integrity and html semantics?

Comment: Can you go into more detail about how this data is used and where it comes from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hidden input will be hidden regardless of the styling rules of the document (CSS), this may make it better performance wise but I don't have the data to show this. Having said that, input controls are meant to be submitted as part of a form.

There are other methods as well, like the HTML5 custom data attributes or using a script tag:

```
<!-- Custom data attribute -->
<div id="product" data-id="42">
    <h1>Product name</h1>
</div>

<!-- JSON data embedded in a script tag -->
<script type="application/json">
    { "id": 42 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

There are many factors involved in performance. But unless you are storing a ton of data the performance differences are likely indistinguishable.

What's best for code integrity and semantics is dependent upon the data and how you are using it.

There are many options for storing data:

- Storing data in a **hidden input** which is great for use with forms:

  `<input name="mydata" type="hidden" value="some data" />`
- Storing data in a **hidden html tags** which is often frowned upon by search engines because of it's abuse in trying to improve SEO ranking:

  `<div id="mydata" style="display:none">
     some data
  </div>`
- Storing data **in javascript** which is great for quick easy access:

  `<script type="text/javascript">
      var data.id = 123;
      var data.list = ["Yes","No","Maybe"];
  </script>`
- Storing data **in a META Tag** which I've used on a rare occasion: http://code.lancepollard.com/complete-list-of-html-meta-tags#create-custom-meta-tags

  `<meta name="mydata" content="some data"/>`
- Storing data **in a cookie** which as long as cookies haven't been disabled this option allows for the data to expire:
  http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
- HTML5 has an **SQLite database**:

  http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/
- HTML5 specs allows for **custom data attributes**

  http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Answer (score 3):

Semantics dictates the answer is - it depends on how you're using it.

If the data needs to be submitted as a form or is closely related to a form then use the input. I'm not sure what situations wouldn't fall in that category, since data that's only used on one page can be stored in a javascript variable if the user shouldn't see it.

Comment: for example you show a list of people and want to hide their ids from user, but it is needed in a click event.

Comment: Have you considered using an attribute? For example id="person123" or rel="123"?

Comment: Looks like this should be updated to mention the html5 data attribute. It's a really easy way to store and pull info using javascript or a breeze with jquery. I couldn't find a concise example to link to but if you google a few articles you can quickly piece together how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that first solution (with input type=hidden) is more pretty, because second solution depends on css, which may be disabled in browser and your data will be shown to user.